# The diagonal braces on the Apollo-era Launch Umbilical Tower (LUT) - oh and the vertical and horizontals too

Tags: saturn-v

Can anyone give me a lead on where to find the exact dimensions of the diagonal braces used on the original (Apollo-Era) Saturn V Launch Umbilical Tower (LUT)?

In fact, while we are at it, I am looking for the exact dimension of the upright steel and horizontal beams on the LUT as well. I am trying to scratch build a 1/100th or 1/96th scale model in brass or some other metal that will withstand the launching of Low Power Rockets (LPR), Mid Power (MPR) as well as eventually High Powered (HPR).

This is going to be a lengthy project but I am patient. I just want to be able to stay as close as possible to what the real thing was.

Thanks for any help you could offer.

Ralph M Bohm

Comment: There used to be http://savethelut.org, which had a ton of information. But it seems to be down. There's [a copy at archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20210411020430/http://savethelut.org/) that may be helpful to get started - I'm sure people made copies of the images. [This](https://web.archive.org/web/20210411020356/http://www.savethelut.org/weeks/) and [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20210411020353/http://www.savethelut.org/maw/) seem to be a good collection of drawings that may be of use.